# window.open cannot find the html file

Tags: javascript, flask

I have this part of ajax code in file1.html:

```
    success: function (response) {
                      respObj = JSON.parse(response);
                      console.log(respObj["data"]);
                      var myWindow = window.open('find_patient.html', 'popup', "width=400,height=100");
                      },
              error: function (error) {
                  console.log(error);
              },
          });
```

I expect to see the new window open, but instead I find it cannot find the file, which of course is in the same directory. Now, my backend is flask, and I see it tries to open "http://localhost:5000/find_patient.html" in new window. Any suggestions please on how do i give it to open the file in same directory, ie root_dir/templates/find_patient.html

Comment: Is it in the web root? If not you need to supply a path that does make sense, like `/templates/find_patient.html`.

Comment: It's odd you're dumping a raw HTML file into a pop-up window, which itself is an anti-pattern to try and avoid. Normally you'd be accessing a Flask endpoint of some kind.

Comment: actually, i am using it to popup a table which will be used to select a data from a row. Any suggestion how I should approach else?

Comment: It's not clear what that means. Is it just static data? Does it have JavaScript to do something in the parent window?

Comment: Are you testing this on a webserver or local filesystem?